# Texas Instruments DCA1000 radar issues

Tags: connection, texas-instruments

I'm using mmWave Studio 2.1.1.0 on Windows 10 to connect to a DCA1000 with AWR1243BOOST module attached. I followed the connection procedure by going under the connection tab, clicking Set (1) and then Disconnect (2), and finally loading the DataCaptureDemo_xWR.lua script and running it. I get one of these two messages:

> MSS Power Up async event was not received!

> BSS Power Up async event was not received!

If instead of running the script I continue by clicking Load(3), Load(4), SPI Disconnect(5), and RF Power-up(6), I get "BSS Power Up async event was not received!"

I would be posting this issue on TI forums but they don't let members of non-partnered institutions post.

Also, I want to try connecting with CLI on Linux, but the mmwave_sdk_user_guide.pdf says I need to run Windows executable files on Linux, which obviously fails. What am I missing?